# Warning: SQLite3::query() [sqlite3.query]: 1 values for 2 columns

Tags: php, sqlite, insert, warnings

I am using an sqlite3 db in php wich i want to fill, i need to fill in a foreign key and the name of the subcategory, here's the code that i use.

```
var_dump('"'.$categoryRow.','.$subcategory.'"');
            $db->query('INSERT INTO Subcategories (fk_cat, subcat) VALUES ("'.$categoryRow.','.$subcategory.'")');
            $subCategoryRow = $db->lastInsertRowID();
            die();
```

But when i run this code, it returns:

```
string(11) ""1,subcategory"" 
Warning: SQLite3::query() [sqlite3.query]: 1 values for 2 columns in /mysite/product.php on line 94
```

but when i log them i get 1 and ''subcategory' back.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variables should be both surrounded by double quotes
sql should be insert into (field1, field2) values ("value1","value2")

```
var_dump('"'.$categoryRow.','.$subcategory.'"');
            $db->query('INSERT INTO Subcategories (fk_cat, subcat) VALUES ("'.$categoryRow.'","'.$subcategory.'")');
            $subCategoryRow = $db->lastInsertRowID();
            die();
```

Comment: You're my hero. Thanks i will accept the answer whenever it can

Comment: Do you maybe know if there's a way to save the database to a file? i need to fill it and save it on disk. is that possible?

Comment: what do you mean by saving the database to a file? it should automatically save.. btw, you need write permissions to the directory where the sqlitedb file resides!